# Final Value Theorem yielding the wrong result?

Tags: signal, control-system, signal-processing, laplace-transform

C1 has an impedance of 1/0.1s Ohm in S-domain. Its impedance together with R1's is 100/(10s+10) Ohm

The transfer function is:
$$\frac{V_2}{V_1}=\frac{5}{\frac{100}{10s+10}+5}=\frac{50s+50}{50s+150}$$

Just looking at this transfer function, because the only pole is has a negative real part, in time domain, it's going to 0. But that is not correct according to the schematic. At time=infinity, C1 is open circuit, so \$V2=(1/3) * V1\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA3xrP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The FVT is speaking of \$sF(s)\$, not just \$F(s)\$.

Comment: How do you model a DC voltage source in the Laplace domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the FVT in Laplace domain \$-\$
$$\lim _{t\to\infty} H(t) = \lim _{s\to0}sH(s)$$
Transfer function is \$-\$
 $$H(s)=V_2(s) = V_1(s).\frac{5}{\frac{100}{10s+10}+5} $$
\$V_1\$ is a DC voltage source.
$$\implies V_2(s)=\frac{V_1}{s}.\frac{5}{\frac{100}{10s+10}+5}$$
@time = infinity,
$$ \lim _{s\to0}sH(s)=\lim _{s\to0}(s.\frac{V_1}{s}.\frac{5}{\frac{100}{10s+10}+5} )$$
$$=\frac{V_1}{3}$$